# Generate cryptographically secure tokens with built-in expiration period

Tags: php, security, token

Is it possible to generate a token with a built-in expiration period? And if so, what would be the most secure way to do it?

To achieve this the generation datetime has to be encoded in the token in a secure matter.

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler just to keep the expiration as a datetime in a database along with the token?

Comment: That's how I would do it normally, which works perfectly fine, but I'm curious if it could be optimized to a single token value.

Comment: Personally, I'm not sure that would be an optimisation. Where would you expect a benefit?

Comment: Storing just a single field instead of two. Of course it's just a small optimisation and could be considered a nice-to-have.

Comment: But then you'd still need to query the database for the token, but you'd have to add an overhead for somehow retrieving the expiry date / time from the token, which would potentially be more costly than the few bytes of the data from an retrieving an additional field. I expect there is a way to do what you're asking, perhaps by encrypting the unique token and the expiry or something, but it seems, overall, an overcomplication :)

Comment: I think JWT has a possibility to set expiration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a JWT in it's simplest form with not befor and not after time defined , you can leave out the claims... JWT fits the bill completely here..

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I needed this without any database in the backend.
You can generate random bytes with a secure entropy source (random_bytes for PHP 7, openssl_random_pseudo_bytes or reading /dev/urandom file directly), then pack the timestamp to bytes: `pack('N', time());` append it to the random bytes and then sign it with HMAC server's key.

Token creation:

```
$random = random_bytes(8);
$time = pack('N', time());
$token = $time . $random;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $SERVER_KEY, true);
$token = $sign . $token;
echo $token;
```

For check:

```
if (strlen($token) !== 44)
   die('Invalid token'); // 32 byte of hash, 4 of timestamp, 8 of random
$hash = substr($token, 0, 32);
$token = substr($token, 32);
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, $SERVER_KEY, true);
if ($hash !== $sign)
   die('Invalid token');
$time = unpack('N', substr($token, 0, 4));
if (time() - $time[1] > $EXPIRY_SECONDS)
   die('Expired token');
//valid
```

Obviously there are a lot of other security aspects to keep in mind, such as Reply-attack that needs store used tokens at least until they expire.
For packing and unpacking the time I've used N flag which is for Big-Endian, but you can also use V for Little-Endian or L for machine-dependent order.

Comment: At first this would be the solution I was looking for, but after reading into JWT it seems be to a better fit. 
+1 for example code

Answer (score 0):

If you sign your token, say with HMAC, you can add anything you want to it, for example an expiration date, or a creation date and check how old it is when you process it to determine if it has expired. The HMAC guarantees that the token can't be modified unless your secret has been compromised.